# Problem with defining an empty array in Nim

Tags: arrays, nim-lang

A few days ago I discovered Nim language and started learning it using a dedicated guide for beginners https://narimiran.github.io/nim-basics. I want to solve one exercise from this tutorial in which I have to build an empty array which can contain 10 integers and then fill it with numbers using a loop. However, when I try to compile my code I get an error:

```
$ nim c array.nim
Hint: used config file '/etc/nim.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: system [Processing]
Hint: array [Processing]
array.nim(4, 1) Error: '=' expected
```

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
const
    a: array[10,int]

var b = 0
var c = 10

for i in a:
    a[b] = c*(b+1)
    inc b
echo a
```

And it seems that the problem is with the beginning of line 4, as the compiler expects "=" as it  is expecting the array's content to be declard. However, according to the tutorial I use, it is possible to declare empty arrays as I did and to fill them later. What should I do to write this one correctly?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a `var` instead of a `const` keyword,

As described in the const [doc](https://narimiran.github.io/nim-basics/#_const):

> The value of an immutable assignment declared with const keyword must be known at compile time (before the program is run).

Because you are initialising an array, you don't know the values before the program is run.

The following code should work:

```
var
    a: array[10,int]

var b = 0
var c = 10

for i in a:
    a[b] = c*(b+1)
    inc b
echo a
```

Comment: well, this time it returned another error message:

array.nim(2, 8) Error: Error: ambiguous identifier: 'array' --use unknown.array or system.array

Comment: @miclis can you check you are running Nim 1.0 with `nim -v`? Older versions would be confused by the name of your file being named `array.nim`, the same as a system module. Chances are if you rename `array.nim` to `a.nim` or something else it should work.

Comment: okayy, thanks for advice. Actually, I was using nim v. 0.17.2 as this is the version I found in a repository of Linux Mint I use. I tried to compile the code on my Windows machine which has Nim 1.0 and everything worked fine. I think I will download the newest version of Nim on my Linux machine and keep learning. Thank you guys!